# SharePoint 2013 - Break inheritance subsite

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, security, inheritance

i want to break the inheritance of a subsite. I know which button I have to press to solve this problem. But if I press this Button in the Ribbon UI in SharePoint, I cann not break the inheritance of this site.

Another try was to use the SharePoint Shell by using this code:

```
$url = http://SharePointSite.com/SubSite
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $url
$web.BreakRoleInheritance($true)
```

But same here, I can not break the inheritance of this site. On other sites Iam able to break the inheritance.
example:

- site/subsite001 --> not able to break inheritance
- site/subsite002 --> able to break inheritance

Iam SharePoint Admin in our Sitecollection but, I dont know why it doesnt work..

It would be very nice, if someone can help me!
Thanks!

Comment: Any error or correlation id?

Comment: Just clearing the obvious..  The permissions page for **site/subsite001** still says that `This Web site inherits permissions from its parent` after you break inheritance?

Comment: Yes, the inheritance is still there . Although I have clicked on the button.

Comment: Even after you break inheritance, it still retains the roles from the parent site until you start editing them.  Are you able to edit the roles of the subsite at all?

Comment: No this is not possible

Comment: ...and, does the PowerShell code return any sort of errors?

Comment: unfortunately no, this is irritating